# How to make dictionary for number of occurrences in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary that will have the length of a string occurrence in a list as keys, and then the number of occurrences as a value.

So for example, if I had this list:

```
x = ['ABC','GOOGLE','BCD','GOOGLY', 'A','A']
```

the dictionary result would look something like this:

```
d = {3:2, 6:2, 1:2}
```

The key 3 represents that in the list, indexes that had a length of 3, there were 2 occurrences ('ABC' and 'BCD').

this was the best attempt I could come up with:

```
d = {len(x.count()):len(x.count())  for (key, value) in x} #wrong
```

How could I go about doing this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in 2 steps, first create a list of lengths of individual items and them create a dictionary from the count list.

```
c = [len(item) for item in x]
d = {item:c.count(item) for item in c}
```

Comment: If there are `x` items in the list, you'll iterate over the entire list `x` times. O(n^2) is very inefficient.

Comment: And also I would do `for item in set(c)`

Answer (score 3):

Create a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object of the lengths of the strings in `x`

```
from collections import Counter

x = ['ABC','GOOGLE','BCD','GOOGLY', 'A','A']

length_counts = Counter(len(word) for word in x)

print(length_counts)
# Counter({3: 2, 6: 2, 1: 2})
```

you can convert it to a dict if you want

```
print(dict(length_counts))
# {3: 2, 6: 2, 1: 2}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without the counter library? Thanks for the answer by the way

Comment: It's built into Python 2 and Python 3; no extra libraries required.

Comment: I know, I'm just curious if there is a way to do it without collections

Answer (score 2):

It seems a lot of people were answering this, but I figured to also throw my 2 cents in.

```
x = ['ABC','GOOGLE','BCD','GOOGLY', 'A','A']
def make_object(arr):
  lengths = (len(item) for item in arr);
  obj = {}
  for item in lengths:
    obj[item] = obj[item] + 1 if item in obj else 1
  return obj

make_object(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def stlen(array):
    di=dict()
    for x in array:
        di.update({len(x):di.get(len(x),0)+1})
    return di

    print(stlen(['hgds','uyrd','et','hgds','uyr']))
```

Result:

```
{4: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
from collections import Counter
x = ['ABC','GOOGLE','BCD','GOOGLY', 'A','A']
dic =Counter(list(map(len,x)))
print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` is definitely the best answer in Python. A more functional-language style answer would look like this (Python 3.5 or later):

```
from functools import reduce

x = ['ABC','GOOGLE','BCD','GOOGLY', 'A','A']
length_counts = reduce(lambda accum, s: {**accum, len(s): accum.get(len(s), 0) + 1}, x, {})
```

or

```
from functools import reduce

x = ['ABC','GOOGLE','BCD','GOOGLY', 'A','A']
length_counts = reduce(lambda accum, i: {**accum, i: accum.get(i, 0) + 1}, map(len, x), {})
```

This general approach is more portable across different languages (but again in this specific question, `Counter` is definitely the right answer).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = dict()

for k, v in groupby(sorted(map(len, x))):
    d[k] = len(list(v))

{1: 2, 3: 2, 6: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Simple Method:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = ['ABC','GOOGLE','BCD','GOOGLY', 'A','A']

print x

d = defaultdict(int)
for a in x:
   d[len(a)] += 1

print d
```

**Output:**

```
['ABC', 'GOOGLE', 'BCD', 'GOOGLY', 'A', 'A']
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 2, 3: 2, 6: 2})
```